# How to join 2 contours

Tags: c#, emgucv

Im trying to build an ocr/ocv app. it works well. But in real world scenarios, printed text is not perfect, it has some defects like ink spread or a cut in between. Inkspread is manageable, but im stuck at how to join the 2 parts of a character when there is a cut, like in the image below:

[image: Letter B]

I find contours before I do ocr/ocv, :

```
        using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
        {

            CvInvoke.FindContours(binaryimg, contours, null, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
            int count = contours.Size;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {

                double perimeter = CvInvoke.ArcLength(contours[i], true);
                VectorOfPoint approx = new VectorOfPoint();
                CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(contours[i], approx, 0.04 * perimeter, true);

                CvInvoke.DrawContours(mainimg, contours, i, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
                Rectangle r = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(approx);
                id++;
                int area = r.Width * r.Height;
                int width = r.Width;
                int height = r.Height;
             }
         }
```

I get the height and width of the character, and inside those rectangle I do OCR and OCV. When there is a cut in character, it gets detected as 2 contours. How do I join those? I tried open and closing but it didnt help much.

Comment: Are you sure you sure detecting contours is the right approach? I would have expected the OCR engine to be Neural network based, and work best with raw image data. Closing *should* work, but you would need careful adjustment of the parameters, to little and you will not close the gaps, to much and any bounded area will be filled.

Comment: Hi Jonas, Im using tesseract and while it does work with raw images without any need for a rect, but I need those for checking print quality. Also, tesseract does not detect that character as B, it detects it as E and 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with OCR, but my understanding is that the first step is usually to use a text-detector to find parts of the image covered by text to form Regions of interest to feed to the OCR algorithm. Creating per character ROIs seem like it could be problematic since some fonts may have very small or even no spacing between some characters. Some OCR engines may benefit from knowing the font.

Assuming the print defects cover more than one character, one option would be to detect and repair that specific defect. You could for example apply a horizontal blur filter, do some thresholding and line detection. Once you found a defect you could try to repair it by finding places where it seem to cut characters, and fill in those places.

Another approach might be to retrain the neural network on your particular dataset and defects to try to improve accuracy.

But it is very likely some errors will still occur. So in the end you might still need to have a human proof-reading the result, or have some system to inform the operator about sections the algorithm is uncertain about.